# Icon disappearing in IE9 and IE10 when rotated

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I am having issue in IE9, IE10 and IOS 8  when used `transform: rotate(180deg)`, the icon is disappearing.

I tried using `-ms` vendor prefix but no use.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rxz4saLa/2/)
[Test on Modern.ie](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/screenshots/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Frxz4saLa%2F2%2Fshow)

```css
.down-arrow {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
svg {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:none">
  <svg>
    <symbol id="down-arrow">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.527,6.854L0.202,1.042c-0.269-0.288-0.269-0.754,0-1.042h8.621
c0.269,0.288,0.269,0.755,0,1.042" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="down-arrow">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#down-arrow"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And I think this is not only with SVG but also when used html elements. Check this example fiddle.

```css
.down-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 12px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="down-arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Tested your snipped here in a IE9 win7 vm and it's looking like it should (9.0.8.112.16421).

Comment: @NicoO I am testing on win7 IE9 too. but not vm.

Comment: Maybe it could help you to get a VM of modern.ie or any other machine and test ist there as well. Hard to tell what is "correct" like this. Still having to support IE9 is a pain. Best of luck. - Just on a side node: Did you test your snippet on this page with IE9?

Comment: @NicoO I just checked on modern.ie, in that also the icon is not visible for ie9 win7. [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/screenshots/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Frxz4saLa%2F2%2Fshow)

Comment: I think this could be a problem regarding jsFiddle, see here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/screenshots/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Frxz4saLa%2F2%2Fshow%2Flight%2F it seems it won't even work with IE11. If you put the same code in a jsbin: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/screenshots/?url=https%3A%2F%2Foutput.jsbin.com%2Ffudeciwaki the results are different, also if IE9 support seems not to be given by this paste bin as well.

Comment: FYI: _"IE 10 and below does not support CSS transforms on SVG elements"_. Source: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: @zeroflagL I thought the same. check my below fiddle in the post without svg. The issue still persist.

Comment: I ran your non-svg snippet on Win7 / IE9 and it transformed correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/t6edkw85/

Comment: also, iOS8 requires the -webkit- prefix.

Comment: hi @Mr_Green have you got a chance to see my post recently, ,it renders icon successfully on IE10, IE9, but no IE8? you can check my fiddle test here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/screenshots/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Fmkdizajn%2Fu2Lsh2sh%2F

Comment: @oserk Thanks. It is working fine on IE9 emulator. need to check on real IE9. will update you soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [SVG for Everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody),

I have created test pen here: http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/PbyZoM also I have tested on WIN 7 and IE9 and image is here:

https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/ic7b2b4fec0f754a/livetests/6573248/snapshots/z1482ad843f3e76a100f

The only thing that I did was that I included external JS file:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg4everybody/2.1.3/svg4everybody.min.js
```

and called

```
svg4everybody();
```

hope that helps

Comment: A team member was supposed to test it on live site but he didn't :P. I hope this works when we again jump to that issue. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks @Mr_Green glad it helped and I'm sure it will work fine :)